# Player isn't seen when the enemy gets close to the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically when the enemy sees the player it approaches the player but once it gets close it goes into its idle state. (there is an image at the bottom showing how close I mean). I am unsure as to why it does that. Also just a note, The I saw the player again message didn't pop up in the console so maybe that has something to do with it. I am new to programming so I am sorry if I have bad code/misunderstood some functions. Thank you and if there is any code needed please just ask and I can give it.

This is the script for finding the player.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerPos : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool FindPlayerPos(float inRange, GameObject playerPos, float inView, GameObject self, bool hasSeenPlayer)
    {
        float distDif = Vector3.Distance(playerPos.transform.position, self.transform.position);
        if (distDif <= inRange && PlayerIsInSight(inView, playerPos, self) && !hasSeenPlayer)
        {
            hasSeenPlayer = true;
            Debug.Log("I see player");
            return hasSeenPlayer;
            
        }

        if (distDif <= inRange && hasSeenPlayer)
        {
            self.transform.LookAt(playerPos.transform.position);
            Debug.Log("I saw the player again");
            return true;
        }
        Debug.Log("I dont see player");
        return false;
    }

   
    public static bool PlayerIsInSight(float inView, GameObject playerPos, GameObject self)
    {
        Vector3 targetDir = playerPos.transform.position - self.transform.position;
        Vector3 forward = self.transform.forward;
        float angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(targetDir, forward, Vector3.up);
        float selfHeight = self.GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.size.y;

        if (angle <= inView && angle >= -inView && playerPos.transform.position.y <= self.transform.position.y + selfHeight/2 + selfHeight && playerPos.transform.position.y >= (self.transform.position.y - selfHeight) - selfHeight / 2)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also this is how I call it in the attack state:

```
if (!PlayerPos.FindPlayerPos(AttackRange, playerPos, inView, self, HasSeenPLayer))
```

attackrange is 3.5

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0egm.png

Comment: Your angle code includes the vertical  difference between the `PlayerPos` transform and the `playerPos` transform (having `playerPos` and `PlayerPos` be very different things is weird naming). What happens if you use `targetDir.y = 0f;`?

Comment: That's a very convoluted way of doing what you want. I suggest just rewriting the code with an arc of multiple raycasts in front of your enemy to detect the player. Also you shouldn't have the enemy code in your player class.

Comment: @MoniqueDumont I heard about raycasts but I have no knowledge on them so I didn't try to use them. Do the unity documents have enough information to do what you are suggesting?

Comment: I think in order to answer this we would need to have more context .. e.g. what does idle state mean here and how and when are your methods called exactly? At first glance: The second case will probably never happen since you never update the value of `HasSeenPLayer` outside of the method .. you might want to use a [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) here ...

Comment: And in the second case I guess you could get rid of most calculation by using `Angle` instead of `SignedAngle` and for the second part of the condition `Mathf.Abs` and compare only absolute values